# Сертификат для разных доменных адресов к одному серверу

Tags: node.js, сервер, ssl, https

У меня есть сервер. Я для него купил домены. Одно имя, но разные доменные зоны - `.ru` и `.online`. Оба предоставлены с бонусным SSL сертификатом.

Сервер на Node.js:

```
const server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem')
});
```

Если в `key.pem` и `cert.pem` у меня сертификат для домена `.online`. При попытке зайти на сайт через домен `.ru` браузер ругается, что сертификат не для того домена. Как обработать, какой сертификат клиенту давать?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_server_addcontext_hostname_context
Или не заморачиваться и поставить перед нодой какой-нибудь сервер (nginx, например) и разбираться с https уже там.

Comment: @AlexeyTen для меня "заморачиваться" - это разбираться в Nginx'ах и Apach'ах. Спасибо за ответ, кажется, это именно то, что мне нужно.